# How to override prestashop's default front-office template and controller in module

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I want to override prestashop's default front-office template and controller in my newly created module without modifying prestashop's internal code/structure.

Example :

I have created one module i.e. "mymodule" in /modules folder where I want use prestashop's address form (address.tpl).

see : http://demo-store.prestashop.com/en/address.

I want to enhance address form by providing some additional fields/functionality but without changing prestashop's core functionality.

So, How can I override its controller/themes/templates in my module? I have searched lot of about this on google but didn't found anything :(

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Modules can work like you ask only if there's an `HOOK` inside the `template/controller` that allow you to run your customized function. Look if you have a chance of hooking your module somewhere by watching on the list showed inside

```
backoffice > modules > position
```

the Address controllers hasn't got any Hook if i recall well, so you have 3 ways to edit its functionality:

1. Go for an (imho) horrible client-side modification, by an heavy usage of jquery/ajax call to perform the action you need. Place the code by using a module that only add your js script in the header by using the `hookHeader()` function. Since this hook it's always called in all the site you can exploit the missing hook in the address template.
2. add yourself an hook inside the Controller and the template by following this procedure: http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/218291-create-custom-and-new-hook-in-ps-15/
3. use the amazing override features of the prestashop framework to modify what you need in the Controller file placed inside your `prestashop_root/override/controllers/front/AddressController.php` and inside your `/prestashop_root/themes/my_theme/address.tpl`. this way you can ovverride any function of the Controller withouth loosing the original functionality and if you'll need to upgrade your installation you will just need to check for the function you changed in the overrided file just as you would do for your module.

Comment: In my module I am overriding address controller. i.e. I created on folder structure like `mymodule/override/controllers/front/addresscontroller.php` and calling the template `address.tpl` in `mymodule/override/views/front/address.tpl` but its not working

Comment: Using `setTemplate` I am trying to execute my `address.tpl` file : `$this->setTemplate(__PS_BASE_URI__.'modules/mymodule/override/views/front/address.tpl');`

Comment: You can't override a controller inside a module, that's going overboard with the default framework autoload function. the autoload will always search for a controller by searching it inside the override folder and for a class name that goes by "ControllerName" where the original controller its called "ControllerNameCore", it will never search for a controller override inside the module folder. you have to puth your files in their right directory so: address.tpl goes in /themes/default/address.tpl and your addresscontroller must be placed in /override/controllers/front/AddressController.php. :)

Comment: just as a note : Letting developers override controllers inside a module would be a cool feature but only in theory, just think about five different modules that all have their AddressController override but with different output, that's why hooks exist. ;)